# jquery mobile page transition not working on exteranl page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile page transition feature in my application (HTML5 Mobile App) with:

```
<a href="test.html" data-transition="slide">abc</a>
```

but it is not working. A popup with a rotator image and loading message comes up and nothing happensa.

Comment: Could you provide some more code?

Comment: Refer my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12370256/500725)**

Answer (score 1):

add the attribute

```
rel="external"

<a href="test.html" data-transition="slide" rel="external">abc</a>
```

> this will load the external pages.. But you cant expect the page trasition animation

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

But in your case, I think you might not using proper jquery mobile `CSS` and `JS` files.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/rfjfQ/1/)**

For more information, refer to **[Page Transitions](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)**

Comment: Your JSFiddle link is exhibiting the same behaviour the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If the loading icon is appearing on pageload (before the link is even clicked) then you almost certainly have a JS error within your calling page.

check the following:

- Your JQM includes are being called in the correct order
  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/about/getting-started.html
- Check for errors in the console

JQM sites can be fairly quirky, and it's hard to provide full samples. If possible show snippets of your  tags and console output.